# Oracle insert into query with 2 select cases

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hello I'm trying to migrate from MySQL to Oracle. So far so good until I came across this query:

```
INSERT INTO waiting 
            (
              dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, 
              dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, 
              dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn, dbcolumn
            ) 
            SELECT 
              (case NVL(max(dbcolumn)) 
                when 0 
                  then max(dbcolumn)+1 
                when 1 
                  then 3 end), 

              (case NVL(max(dbcolumn))
                when 0 
                  then max(dbcolumn)+2 
                when 1 
                  then 4 end), 

              "value" , "value" , "" , "value" , "value" , 
              "value" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "value" , "" , "" , "value" , "value" 
            FROM waiting 
            WHERE dbcolumn < value;
```

The values who are empty can be null. 
When I try to run the query it gives me: `"missing right parenthesis"`
But that doesn't seem right because I'm closing all parenthesis.

Can someone give me the magic answer why I get this error message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the syntax of NVL function is NVL( string1, replace_with )..

Comment: @ravikumar thanks. But still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be something like this

`(case
         WHEN NVL(max(dbcolumn), '0') = 0 THEN
          max(dbcolumn1) + 1
         when NVL(max(dbcolumn), '0') = 1 then
          3
       end)`

In oracle, the value you intend to match comes after `when`.

Comment: Not if you're just matching on equality. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do `NVL(max(dbcolumn),0)` instead of `NVL(max(dbcolumn))`

Don't use parenthesis for `CASE` :

```
SELECT case NVL(max(dbcolumn),0) 
            when 0 
              then max(dbcolumn)+1 
            when 1 
              then 3 end,
```

And I'm not sure but use single quote `'` instead of double quote `"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix *both* the malformed NVLs, the `missing right parenthesis` error will go away. However, there is another consideration you may not have noticed. If (for the first column) MAX returns null or 0, the NVL returns 0 and the CASE returns 1. If the NVL returns 1, the CASE returns 3. That appears to be what you want. If, however, the NVL returns any other value, the CASE returns NULL. If that is also what you want, then you're fine. If you want any other value, you must provide it in an ELSE.

Here is the SELECT part of the statement, simplified just to three columns with distinguishing names, which shows an example:

```
SELECT  CASE NVL( MAX( Col1 ), 0 ) 
              WHEN 0 THEN 1 -- if A = 0 then A+1 = 1
              WHEN 1 THEN 3
              ELSE MAX( Col1 )
        END AS NewCol1, 
        case NVL( MAX( Col2 ), 0 )
              WHEN 0 THEN 2 
              WHEN 1 THEN 4
              ELSE MAX( Col2 )
        END AS NewCol2, 
        'value' as NewCol3
FROM waiting 
WHERE col1 < Value;
```